# Secure Google Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, google-signin

I need to make a query to one of Google's services. I read this answer: [download csv from google insight for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656446/download-csv-from-google-insight-for-search/1656817#1656817)
The copied and pasted code from that question is:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // TODO: put your real email and password in the request string
        var response = client.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=youraccount@gmail.com&Passwd=secret&service=trendspro&source=test-test-v1");
        // The SID is the first line in the response
        var sid = response.Split('\n')[0];
        client.Headers.Add("Cookie", sid);
        byte[] csv = client.DownloadData("http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=test&cmpt=q&content=1&export=2");

        // TODO: do something with the downloaded csv file:
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(csv));
        File.WriteAllBytes("report.csv", csv);
    }
```

and I want to know whether sending the password in the string is secure or can it be grabbed?

If this is not secured, how should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it uses [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) (not plain HTTP) it should be about as secure as most anything else can ever be on the net.  All data, including the URL, travel on an encrypted channel once the underlying TLS connection's established.

Comment: Thanks for the link to https. I have no clue regarding web programming or anything related to it, but the article explains it in my language of the OSI model.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those "good news, bad news" situations.

Good news: The password can't be grabbed by an eavesdropper (because it is sent over HTTPS: encrypted).

Bad news: the session cookie can be grabbed by an eavesdropper (because it is sent over HTTP: not encrypted).  As Firesheep has demonstrated, letting someone get access to your Google session cookie is dangerous, as it gives the attacker access to your email and other content stored on Google.

If you can change the `http` URL to a `https` URL, that would be safer.