# Trying to login into Google in order to download Google Trends data

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to:

1. Login to Google
2. Download CSV data from Google Trends

I am succeeding in (1) but not in (2). I get returned an authorization-token from Google, and am sending it with the subsequent request to Trends, but nevertheless Google then returns an error: "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends":

```
// http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html
$data = array(
  'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
  'Email'       => 'my.email@gmail.com',
  'Passwd'      => 'my.password',
  'service'     => 'trendspro',
  'source'      => 'company-application-1.0'
);

$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);

  // We now have an authorization-token
  $headers = array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $matches[1],
    "GData-Version: 3.0"
  );

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=MSFT&date=2011-2&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
  $csv = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Returns : "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends"
// Expected: CSV data stream
print_r($csv);
```

For some reason, the auth-tokens I am sending to Google Trends, is not being accepted or ignored. I don't know exactly what happens, since no additional error-information is given.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? If you can get it to work, meaning that Google is returning the CSV data, then the bounty is yours and we both have a late Christmas present :-)

---

So I figured out the problem has nothing to do with cURL. What I did was:

- Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=my.email@gmail.com&Passwd=my.password&service=trendspro&source=ding-dang-1. The return is:

> ```
> SID=DQAAAMUAAADMqt...aYPaYniC_iW
> LSID=DQAAAMcAAACI5...YDTBDt_xZC9
> Auth=DQAAAMgAAABm8...trXgqNv-g0H
> ```

- I copy the returned Auth token: DQAAAMgAAABm8...trXgqNv-g0H
- I send a GET request using the POSTman Chrome extension to http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=MSFT&date=2011-2&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N using the header:

> ```
> GData-Version: 3.0     
> Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAMgAAABm8...trXgqNv-g0H
> ```

- I get returned:

headers:

> ```
> Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2011 00:17:20 GMT
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Disposition: filename=trends.csv
> Content-Length: 97
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> Server: Google Trends
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
> Cache-Control: private
> ```

data:

> ```
> You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends
> ```

In other words, I'm sending headers as defined by Google on http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html but no luck getting a proper return. An there is about * no * info on the Interwebs concerning this. Who knows what the problem is here?

Comment: Have you checked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986758/oauth-google-trends-download-csv-file

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Your link brought me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656446/download-csv-from-google-insight-for-search, but this also doesn't fix the problem. I'm doing exactly as explained over there but no luck, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but one guy had a problem with accessing HTTPS websites using cURL and his problem was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316099/cant-connect-to-https-site-using-curl-returns-0-length-content-instead-what-c

Comment: As said, curl_error() doesn't return anything and adding curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem"); doesn't make any difference either: "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends". This is driving me insane...

Comment: curl_getinfo returns: Array ( [url] => http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=MSFT&date=2011-2&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N [content_type] => text/csv; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 274 [request_size] => 458 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 20 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.39 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.047 [pretransfer_time] => 0.047 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 112 [speed_download] => 287 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 881 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0.39 [redirect_time] => 0 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking your code, the problem is that Google Trends needs the `SID` key and not `Auth`. Here's the code I wrote to download the csv's

```
<?php

header('content-type: text/plain');

// Set account login info
$data['post'] = array(
  'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',  // indicates a Google account
  'Email'       => '',  // full email address
  'Passwd'      => '',
  'service'     => 'trendspro', // Name of the Google service
  'source'      => 'codecri.me-example-1.0' // Application's name, e.g. companyName-applicationName-versionID
);

$response = xhttp::fetch('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', $data);

// Test if unsuccessful
if(!$response['successful']) {
    echo 'response: '; print_r($response);
    die();
}

// Extract SID
preg_match('/SID=(.+)/', $response['body'], $matches);
$sid = $matches[1];

// Erase POST variables used on the previous xhttp call
$data = array();

// Set the SID in cookies
$data['cookies'] = array(
    'SID' => $sid
);
```

This uses my [xhttp class](http://codecri.me/sources/includes/class-xhttp-php/), a cURL wrapper.

Comment: Your xhttp class link redirects to a random ad page

Answer (score 2):

**Right tool for the right job**, have you considered [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/)?

It could be even more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I haven't worked w/ Google APIs yet, but wanted to get into the Google Apps API for an upcoming project so started digging around.  My guess is that since Trends isn't in [the list of services that implement the Google Data Protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html) even though you're authenticating correctly / successfully (verified by the Auth section of the response) Google won't honor the auth token for Trends (again this is a best guess!).

My thought then is that you would need to use a traditional method to login to Google Trends and download the CSV, which is to say, act like a browser from your client rather than an app.  Not sure on that, but I found [an older python client on github](https://github.com/suryasev/unofficial-google-trends-api) that claims to be able to download CSVs from Google Trends.  There's also [a blog post on the client](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/programmatic-google-trends-api/).  You may be able to reverse engineer it into a PHP equivalent, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google doesn't officially condone any script-based usage of trends. This would explain why your auth is failing as it's not accepting api connections. Try using a webclient library to capture a cookie and use it to harvest data. This was the solution used by that previously linked [python client on git](https://github.com/suryasev/unofficial-google-trends-api).

On a potentially unrelated note, you use service trendspro but this is the service name for google insights. Try just service => 'trends'